# Why passing a linked list pointer to a function from main() affects the linked list in main?

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm writing a program in C. The program receives file path from standard input to a file which contains data. Then linked list is built from the data. The linked list has to be circular however for simplicity sake (for adding nodes, printing the list) I'm transforming the circular list into a regular non-circular linked list. This is done with `uncirc` function. In the end I assemble the list back to circular structure using `circ` function.

I'm passing a pointer to the linked list to the function `printList` which prints the contents of the list. However, after using `uncirc` from inside `printList` the list actually remains "uncirc"-ed even the main. As far as I know pointers are passed by value so doing anything with the list inside `printList` should not have affected the original list.

The code is below (I included only the essential function pertaining to the problem, otherwise the code would pretty large). I suspect some if you could say that I could easily print the list even in circular structure but would truly bothers me is that the original list is altered from a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN 300
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 300
#define MATERIAL_LEN 100
#define FIELDS_IN_LIGHTING_NUM 8

enum l_type {
    TABLE = 1, WALL, CEILING
};

typedef struct Lighting {
    enum l_type type;
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;
    int bulbs;
    char material[MATERIAL_LEN];
    int strength;
    struct Lighting * next;
} Lighting;

char * getFileName();
int getVolume(Lighting * light);
Lighting * uncirc(Lighting * light);
Lighting * circ(Lighting *light);
void addNode(Lighting **head,  FILE *fd);
void printNode(Lighting * light);
void printList(Lighting * light);
int countLines(FILE *fd);
void printMaxLight(Lighting * light);

int main() {
    FILE * fd;
    char * path;
    Lighting * n1 = NULL;
    int linesInFile, lightNum, i;
    path = getFileName();
    if(!(fd = fopen(path, "r+"))) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", path);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", path);
        exit(0);
    }

    linesInFile = countLines(fd);
    lightNum = linesInFile / 7;

    for(i = 0; !(feof(fd)) && i < lightNum; i++) {
        addNode(&n1, fd); //read file data and create node
                          //7 lines of data are required to create node                                                     
    }

    fclose(fd);
    printList(n1); //print the linked list
    return 0;
}

Lighting * uncirc(Lighting * light) {
    Lighting * p = light;

    if(p == NULL) {
        return p;
    }
    while(p -> next != light) {
        p = p -> next;
    }

    p -> next = NULL;
    return light;
}

Lighting * circ(Lighting *light) {
    Lighting * p = light;

    if(p == NULL) {
        return p;
    }
    while(p -> next != NULL) {
        p = p -> next;
    }
    p -> next = light;
    return light;
}

void printList(Lighting * light) {
    Lighting * p;
    p = uncirc(light);
    if(p == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list\n");
        return;
    }

    while(p != NULL) {
        printNode(p);
        p = p -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `the list actually remains "uncirc"-ed even the main` ? And what's the point of using the `uncirc` function when all it does is return its argument ?

Comment: Related, the sense of `uncirc` is questionable, since by the looks of it, the only purpose is to break the circular nature of the list for an enumeration loop that could just-as-well have been done by the very enumeration logic that broke the circle in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're right but then I stumbled upon this problem which is important for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list isn't **contained** in the pointer. Only the address of the first element is there. And you are not trying to modify what address the pointer in main is containing at any point.

If you pass the address of the first element, and then use it to traverse the list and modify the elements, naturally it will be visible when you use the same address for traversal again.

---

Side note

```
while(p -> next != light) {
```

If the list you pass isn't circular, this will be an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't understand: if I were to iterate over the list in `printList` and for iteration I would use `light = light -> next` which is the argument that `printList` receives, the original list in `main` wouldn't shrink to nothing. However `uncirc` leaves permanent changes.

Comment: @Yos - You are confused because you are treating the pointer as your list, when it isn't. Both `circ` and `uncirc` don't try to change the address that the pointer contains. They only ever make modifications to the memory. Think of it this way: if I rearrange my house, it doesn't mean its address changes and I need to update all my acquaintances. They can still find me at the same address.

Comment: That's right but why iterating `light = light -> next` from `printList` (if I were to use such way to iterate) wouldn't rearrange the original list?

Comment: @Yos - Because you wrote the address of the first house on a piece of paper. Then you went there and got the address of the second house. You wrote that *over your own piece of paper*, you didn't modify the piece of paper in the first house. So the logical structure of the list remains the same.

Comment: and if my function would've received double pointer `**light` then it would change the original "piece of paper"? :)

Comment: @Yos - Yup. Someone didn't just copy their paper for you, but handed you their original one. If you keep overwriting it and hand it back, they will see only your latest modification on it.

Comment: I still think about this: is my logic correct that if I pass a pointer to a linked list to a function and I add nodes somewhere in the middle or end, the changes will be reflected in main as well. However, I wouldn't be able to add a new node to the beginning of the list (new head), because the new node would point to the address of the copied pointer.

Comment: @Yos - Yes. You'd need to pass a pointer to a pointer. In general, you always pass a pointer to what the function may need to modify. If that thing is a pointer, then you pass a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes "*pointers are passed by value*" but anything the pointers point to are **not** "passed by value". That is, the list itself is not copied.

So if you change the list pointed to in a function, the list is just changed!

Comment: wouldn't I need to pass a double pointer to actually perform changes on the original list?

Comment: Yes, you would need to because also the starting element of the list can change, which would not be reflected in the calling function.